# Seeking some guidance regarding rendering layouts in CakePHP v3.3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have downloaded a Bootstrap HTML template from the internet.Now i am planning to convert it to CakePHP (ver 3.3) template.I have copied and pasted all the relevant asset files in `webroot/` folder.Also i have created 3 files namely head.ctp, header.ctp & footer.ctp `inside src/Template/Element.`

Now this html template has menu like home, about us, services, contact us etc.My question is should i create layouts like home.ctp, about_us.ctp, services.ctp & contact_us.ctp inside `src/Template/Element/Layout`?.If yes then how do i use these layouts?I want to use a router which will direct to appropriate layouts.

Please advise with codes.I ask these basic questions because i am quite new to cakephp.

Comment: Read carefully here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts

Comment: You dont have to; just create a single layout `defaut.ctp` is already there. inside insert the elements. for the pages, the `PagesController::display` can handle them easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but some code would have been better

Comment: Read the manual? There is code is well, but code is worthless if you don't bother to understand what it does by reading the whole chapter about views and layouts.

Answer (score 0):

```
You do not need to create separate layouts for menus. In cakephp, layout is just like a template that you can use for your website and Elements are reusable blocks of code that you can use on you ctp file.

Just create a single file in layout folder for e.g home.ctp and add head, header and footer element in that.


    <?= $this->element('head'); ?>
    <?= $this->element('header); ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    <?= $this->element('footer); ?>

Add your title and meta tags in head element. Your menu in header element and your footer in footer element.

Then to set this layout you can simply use following in your initialize function of controller.

    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('home')
```